How can I cast the error type on TRPC client?
I am using TRPC on my next client and I am trying to configure the onError on queries to show a toast with the error.message:
queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            retry: false,
            onError: (error: TRPCClientErrorLike<AppRouter>): void => {

              toast.error(error.message);
              router.replace("/home", { scroll: false });
            },
          },

First I was just using error: any but couldn't access the error.error[0].message property correctly so reading this thread https://github.com/trpc/trpc/discussions/1648 I tried casting the error type with TRPCClientErrorLike<AppRouter> but I keep getting this error:
Type '(err: TRPCClientErrorLike<AppRouter>) => void' is not assignable to type '(err: unknown) => void'

Any idea how can I cast the correct type for the error so I can access the error.error[0].message property ?
